# is it normal to never have been promoted?

Tags: promotion, demotion

After having worked for over 30 years in hierarchical businesses, it seems odd that Ive never earned a promotion.  Ive been demoted at least 2x by having my responsibilities severely trimmed.  For years I turned myself inside out to get a promotion, but it never happened, so I thought Id try a different tack and not try to advance my career, that did not work either.  I had asked managers about it and was rebuffed so severely, it was clearly counterproductive.

Comment: I suggest you remove the parts about "career porn", "freaks of nature" and stochastics. It's irrelevant (and probably insulting to some).

Comment: About "no promotion, but demotions": Slacker, no skills compared to your coworkers, ...? If your manager "rebuffs" your question instead of telling some things that could help, this could be an indication too that your manager isn't satisfied with your work.

Comment: Do you use that kind of language at work?  You think that attitude is healthy?

Comment: Sorry you feel unfulfilled. Unfortunately, we don't have enough information to answer this for your situation. What do you consider a "promotion" (e.g. getting "Senior" put in front of your job title, but essentially having the same job vs. being put in a position of supervising others)? Are you in an organization in which you can be promoted, or are you in a "Mom & Pop" where everyone who has not left for other opportunities has been in the same job for years? What industry are you in? Are your peers being promoted and you're not?

Comment: I think this depends heavily on industry, the company/companies you've worked for, etc. For example, at my present job there is absolutely no room for vertical growth. It's a good job, but I will never be "promoted" because there are no provisions for people rising in the ranks for anything short of 20+ years of service when one manager may retire. One guy has worked here for 8 years, and still has the same work description. He's happy with it, but if he wanted to make team leader, or get into management he'd have to leave. Sometimes you have to take some chances to grow.

Comment: @AndreiROM That's especially true for factory workers and government workers. Take for example the DMV, or a toll booth, some of those people do that very same thing for decades and retire doing what they did since day 1. However, the benefits they get from pension and otherwise probably outweighs a lot of people's big career where when they leave they get nothing other than hopefully a 401k or their savings.

Comment: When you say your manager 'rebuffed you so severely', what do you mean he said? And what have your annual assessment of your performance said?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'promotion'? Do you mean having people report to you? Or do you just mean additional responsibilities? Or an upgraded job title?

Comment: It isn't "normal" to be demoted either. I think you have answered your own question...

Comment: While you say you have never been promoted, have you advanced to more senior positions by changing jobs?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, good to see some points that I did not include in my commentary mentioned.  deviantfan: in all the reviews  the highest ratings, with the exception of 3, yes the bad things were my fault I own it.  the last 'bad' one was 13 years ago.

Comment: paparazzi: normally, I avoid the pejorative language at work, but this has probably hurt me when Ive slipped in the past.  Ive certainly heard plenty from my managers.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Currently, the reaction is that promotion is an absurd request.  Well thats reality.  In other work situations, managers have responded similarly. Once one manager responded with some plausibility and I did all kinds of things above and beyond my responsibilities, I worked very hard for several years, but in the end the same manager said "if you want a career, it wont be here".

Comment: @DJClayworth: promotion to me means the next higher title, recognition of the accomplishment, new responsibilities and commensurate increase in pay.  I did get a title improvement once, 28 years ago, but it was to be kept secret so no one would know.  Ive only worked at 4 places, once I did get new responsibilities and title when I went to a new organization. That was 25 years ago.

Comment: Could you please edit that info into the question.

Comment: @AndreiROM: thanks, good points, there was a point in time where I thought that my ambition to move up was a risk to my family, it was a zero sum game, I had to short change my family to do enough to move up and it seemed I was being selfish, so I changed course and just did a good job at my job and stopped trying to go above and beyond.

Comment: @DJClayworth: made edits, Im a newbie here, so learning as I go, thanks for your input

Comment: @Carson63000: Once I did get a more senior position by moving to a new organization.  That might count.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> Is it normal to never have been promoted over a 30 year career?

No, it definitely isn't.

Figure every year or so you have a review. That's 30 chances at a promotion that you missed. Pure dumb luck should have netted you at least a few, because most companies will often promote you just for staying there for 5+ years "man, Bob's been here for 5 years and we've promoted everyone else - might as well give him a shot".

There are some odd situations that may contribute to this. If you own your own company, you're not going to get promoted (or you only have yourself to blame). If you work for a tiny place where there's no room for growth, you might not get promoted. If you work in a peculiar industry (say... as a minister) where promotion is frowned upon or limited, then you might not get promoted. If you change jobs frequently, then you might not have the reviews to get promoted in-job.

But outside of that, and not knowing more, I would guess that you did something to actively prevent it.

Comment: Dumb luck very rarely gets you a promotion, no matter how many years you try.

Comment: @DJClayworth Perhaps replace "dumb luck" with "being competent enough to avoid being fired". Telastyn is correct that over 30 years even someone with zero ambition barely doing his 9-to-5 will have been promoted at some point.

Comment: @DJClayworth - sure, it is _very rare_. But even 1/100 odds with 30 attempts is a non-trivial opportunity to hit _once_.

Comment: I think my point is - it's not a game of chance.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Having witnessed overt incompetence getting a promotion several times, this makes me realize, often the 'space' in the hierarchy has to be available, whether its real or imaginary.

Answer (score 4):

Yes I believe it is possible to never get promoted while others who came on board after you do get promoted. And I don't think it's always about being the "worst" performer.

I do hope you get a pay raise of sort, though.

In my previous work I have seen several individuals who never been promoted and actually been demoted from a higher position. These people worked at this job for 10-14 years. Then again even the people who do get "promoted" never actually do change except by title, pay, and some additional responsibilities. I only seen one person rise above the current manager. Even for myself, I never been promoted outside of title and pay raise changes. Personally I think it's all about being at the right place at the right time. It's all about attitude, presentation and the general culture of the place and mostly just being at the right place at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

I know someone who's exactly in the same position as yourself. She has been in employment for 33 years with the same organization and although she kept trying for promotions she never made it.  Her colleagues got promoted but mostly new people made it to higher positions.  She was also unfortunately demoted due to some re-organization.

I agree that being at the right place at the right time and having good leaders who will recognize and promote their employees are a few things that will determine your progress in any company.